# Why do I get an error when logging into my Spotify through spotipy?

Tags: python, authentication, jupyter-notebook, spotify, spotipy

I am using Spotify to analyze my playlists for a personal project.

When authorizing access to my own account data, I get to the point where a new Spotify tab opens, and it should prompt me to log in, but it shows an error instead.

[image: Error - Spotify]

If I paste that link in an incognito window, it actually does prompt me to log in:

[image: Login - Spotify]

But as soon as I insert my username & password and press enter, it goes back to the same error page. Meanwhile, in the notebook I get prompted with *"Enter the URL you were redirected to"*, but if I do paste the URL then everything crashes, giving this error:

> SpotifyOauthError: error: invalid_request, error_description: code must be supplied.

Does anybody have any idea as to why this is happening and how I can fix it?

This is the code I'm using (writing in a Jupyter Notebook):

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

spotify = spotipy.Spotify()

cid = "x"
secret = "y"
username = "z"
uri = "localhost:8888"

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

scope = 'user-library-read playlist-read-private'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, cid, secret, uri)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth, SpotifyClientCredentials

# Scope for required features (This is the total avaiable scope, use the ones you want)
scope = "ugc-image-upload user-read-recently-played user-top-read user-read-playback-position user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state user-read-currently-playing app-remote-control streaming playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private playlist-read-private playlist-read-collaborative user-follow-modify user-follow-read user-library-modify user-library-read user-read-email user-read-private"

client_data = {"client_id": "x",
               "client_secret": "y"}

# Spotify's login details
creds = SpotifyClientCredentials(**client_data) #This doesn't require authentication  
auth = SpotifyOAuth({**client_data, "scope": scope,
                    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8080"}) #This is the one you need to use to manage / control your account

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth)
```

You can pass [credentials](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyClientCredentials) if you just want to get data from Spotify, to edit you have to use [SpotifyOAuth](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth).
Check out [examples](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#examples) for more info